# Security measures for storing base64 encoded images in PHP through Android

Tags: php, android

I have an api which accepts image in base64 encoded format from an android app, stores in in a location.
The code that I found online for doing so is :

```
// Get image string posted from Android App
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    // Get file name posted from Android App
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    // Decode Image
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    // Images will be saved under 'www/imgupload/uplodedimages' folder
    $file = fopen('uploadedimages/'.$filename, 'wb');
    // Create File
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
```

- I am a bit concerned about the security of the content that is
  coming. In case of multipart form data I had lots of methods to check
  the image. Don't know what measures to take in this case. Is this
  secure enough ?
- Also can the image be posted in multipart form data from android
  to this api ?
- Or can I convert it to form data at the server end ?

Comment: `$binary=base64_decode($base);` - not later than after this line, your "methods to check the image" should work on $binary. E.g. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php

Comment: Sounds interesting. Let me check !

Answer (score 1):

I had my own, maybe not so popular way! 
I add some special string in beginning of the base 64 string, and in php, I check for it, if it was present, I know it was from my app and I remove the string from the base64 and decode and save the image! 
The php code, is it me thing like this :
Here $base is the base 64 string came from app, which should have the prefix!

```
// here, $prefix, is the string that we added in the beginning of our base64 string 
$prefix = "*%%*SOME_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS*%%*"; 
if (substr($base, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) { 
   $base = substr($base, strlen($prefix)); 
} else { 
   networkError("CHAR", -2); 
} 
// Decode Image 
$binary = base64_decode($base);
```

Of curse still a professional hacker can hack this, but they hack anything

Comment: Interesting.
But if someone intercepts the request then he/she can easily get the pattern.
I was thinking of implementing a method in which I would reproduce the image from the binary and if it turns out to be valid then store it.

Comment: @Ashish well, the point of having a not standard method is that no body is gonna guess that you have done that!

Comment: @Ashish plus you can also put this literal String some where is the middle of your base 64 string and look for it on that position in server! This way I think it's really hard for anyone to figure that out! Plus you can confuse them with incorrect responses :))

Comment: I find it as a good method. But still will keep my eyes looking for better answers(if any). 
Thanks !